# L'emploi du mot "œdipe" pour désigner l'homme pouvant résoudre facilement des énigmes

Tags: usage, grec

Tiré par wiktionnaire :

> Homme qui trouve facilement le mot des énigmes ou la solution de
>   questions obscures. Il faudrait être un œdipe pour deviner ce que cela
>   veut dire. — Je ne suis pas un œdipe.

Cet emploi du mot *œdipe* est-il assez répandu ? Peut-on utiliser le mot couramment ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Je pense que l'emploi du mot *œdipe* dans ce sens là* est très très rare de nos jours et ne doit être compris que de très peu de gens. 
Je ne le trouve que dans un seul des dictionnaires papier à ma disposition, le *Dictionnaire culturel en langue française* qui signale qu'il est vieilli, ce qu'omet de mentionner le [TLF](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/%C5%93dipe).

Le mot  est peut-être plus spécifiquement connu des amateurs de mots-croisés, car *œdipe* est un terme parfois utilisé pour désigner un cruciverbiste (parce que les cruciverbistes résolvent des énigmes).

Je pense que si tu dis à quelqu'un que tu es un œdipe (ou que tu n'en es pas un) la première chose à laquelle il pensera c'est que tu fais allusion au complexe d’Œdipe et il aura du mal à comprendre ce que tu veux dire.

Dans la vie courante on parle d'un [*devin*](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/devin) :
  - Je ne peux pas te répondre, je ne suis pas devin.

---

<sub>*Sens qui se réfère au fait que Œdipe résolu l'[énigme du Sphynx](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%89nigme_du_Sphinx).</sub>